# How to custom the MonthViewHeaderFormat of telerik:RadCanlendar on windows phone 8.1?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, telerik

I am new with Telerik controls and I have a problem, I want to custom the MonthViewHeader of the RadCalendar (sorry if I call it incorrectly) but I don't know how to do that, can you guys please help me!

p/s: I want to custom the red border area!

[image]

Comment: You'll have to dig through the style templates and find the template for that part. In their documentation they call it the "Navigation Control" however this is a really broad question.

Comment: can you help me for this, I break through this but just about customizing the layout of of date, time... but in this occasion, I want to change the format of the header and the navigation buttons of this, do you know some examples for this?